# Imagemagick: channel gets lighter after separate/combine operation

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to combine PBR normal/roughness/metallic map images (.png) into a single RGBA image (also .png), with the normal map in the red and green channels, the roughness map in the blue channel, and the metallic map in the alpha channel.

The following bash command line works, but for some reason the green channel is slightly lighter in the composite image than it is in the original normal image (e.g. a value of 0x7e in the original is raised to 0x87 in the composite). All three other channels keep their original values. If I switch the order of the red and green separation, it's the red channel in the final image that gets lighter. What could be causing that, and how do I avoid it?

```
convert ImageName_Normal.png -colorspace sRGB -write mpr:NORMAL_R -channel R -separate +channel \
-write mpr:NORMAL_G -channel G -separate +channel +delete \
ImageName_Roughness.png -colorspace Gray -flatten -write mpr:ROUGHNESS +delete \
ImageName_Metallic.png -colorspace Gray -flatten -write mpr:METALLIC +delete \
mpr:NORMAL_G mpr:NORMAL_R mpr:ROUGHNESS -combine -write mpr:RGBCOMP +delete \
mpr:RGBCOMP mpr:METALLIC -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite -depth 8 \
png32:ImageName_NormRoughMetal.png
```

ImageMagick version is 6.9.11-60

I tried different variations on it - using `\( +clone` , another copy of the normal map (with and without `+delete` after the first one), and so on. None of them worked any better (and some actually gave me two copies of the normal map's red channel even though green was specified on the command line for the second one).

Comment: When you flatten, the default color is white for the background. Perhaps specify -background black will help.  Also I do suggest using parentheses to ensure you do not mix color channels. Can you post an  example input and output. Post to some free hosting service and put the URL in your post or a comment.

Comment: @fmw42: `-background black` didn't alter the result (I didn't expect it would, as the channels for which I used `-flatten` were coming out correctly already); no change when using parentheses either.  

Example files are [here](https://shipbrook.net/temp/ImageMagickExample.zip).  

However, I just noticed that with or without parentheses, when I pull the second channel from another copy of the normal image (instead of performing a second operation on the single copy), *both* channels come out too light. Which makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Is your input data linear or non-linear?  Perhaps you want to use -colorspace RGB rather than sRGB. That would make the data linear and darker.

Comment: @fmw42: it makes them way too dark (also, `identify` indicates that the original's using the sRGB colorspace). And again, the first channel that it separates is correct in the final image, identical to the corresponding channel in the original image (as are the two channels pulled in from other images). It's just, for some reason, the second channel separated that gets lighter (and even more puzzling, it's not a uniform increase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think your command is what you want in Imagemagick. I think you are not keeping the first two parts properly separate.

Try this

```
convert TestImage_Normal.png -colorspace sRGB -write mpr:NORMAL +delete \
\( mpr:normal -channel R -separate +channel -write mpr:NORMAL_R +delete \) \
\( mpr:normal -channel G -separate +channel -write mpr:NORMAL_G +delete \) \
\( TestImage_Roughness.png -colorspace Gray -flatten -write mpr:ROUGHNESS +delete \) \
\( TestImage_Metallic.png -colorspace Gray -flatten -write mpr:METALLIC +delete \) \
\( mpr:NORMAL_G mpr:NORMAL_R mpr:ROUGHNESS -combine -write mpr:RGBCOMP +delete \) \
mpr:RGBCOMP mpr:METALLIC -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite -depth 8 \
png32:TestImage_NormRoughMetal_fred.png
```